# How to calculate equivalent resistance for a network of same-value resistors?

Tags: functions, function-construction, algorithm

Let's assume I have `n` identical resistors. I can connect them either in series or in parallel (let's disregard bridge connections for now). Now, I want to list all possible connections along with their equivalent resistances.

**For example:**

"pp" represents a parallel connection.
"ss" represents a series connection.

1. With one resistor, we have just "R."
2. With two resistors, we can have: 
   {R pp R, R/2} - Two resistors in parallel, equivalent resistance is R/2.
   {R ss R, 2R} - Two resistors in series, equivalent resistance is 2R.
3. For three resistors, we get:
   {R pp R pp R, R/3} - Three resistors in parallel, equivalent resistance is R/3.
   {(R pp R) ss R, 3R/2} - Two resistors in parallel, then in series with one resistor, equivalent resistance is 3R/2.
   {(R ss R) pp R, 2R/3} - Two resistors in series, then in parallel with one resistor, equivalent resistance is 2R/3.

I would like to present this information in a way that allows me to reconstruct the circuit and know the equivalent resistance of the circuit. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this for any number of resistors?

**EDIT:**

These are the formulas for resistors in series or in parallel:

The equivalent resistance of resistors in series is calculated by adding their individual resistances:
R1 ss R2 ss R3 ss ... Rn = R1 + R2 + R3 + ... + Rn

The equivalent resistance of resistors in parallel is determined by taking the reciprocal of the sum of the reciprocals of their individual resistances:
R1 pp R2 pp R3 pp ... Rn = (1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 + ... + 1/Rn)^-1

I want to find the minimum number of resistors together with the circuit connections to get a given equivalent resistance value.
This is a related post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160766/how-many-resistors-are-needed

Answer (score 6):

You can represent a circuit with binary trees containing two binary operators, `p` and `s`. For example, two resistors in series, then in parallel with one resistor:

```
p[R, s[R, R]]
```

Now we define a function for calculating the equivalent resistance:

```
eq[c_] := c //. {p[R1_, R2_] :> 1/(1/R1 + 1/R2), s[R1_, R2_] :> R1 + R2}

eq[p[R, s[R, R]]]
(* 2R/3 *)
```

To get all possible circuits, use [`Groupings`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings.html). For example, all possible circuit resistances for three equivalent resistors with resistance $R$:

```
Groupings[{R, R, R}, {p -> {2, Orderless}, s -> {2, Orderless}}]
(* {p[p[R, R], R], p[s[R, R], R], s[p[R, R], R], s[s[R, R], R]} *)

eq /@ %
(* {R/3, (2 R)/3, (3 R)/2, 3 R} *)
```

For higher $n$, however, we will also get some circuits that have the same equivalent resistance. We can use [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html) to remove them:

```
allCircuits[n_] := 
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[
  Groupings[Table[R, n], {p -> {2, Orderless}, s -> {2, Orderless}}], eq]
```

This method, however, is still inefficient for larger $n$ because it first enumarates all possible circuits (the number grows as [OEIS A248748](https://oeis.org/A248748)), then remove duplicates.

The number of possible circuits with unique equivalent circuits grows as:

```
Table[Length[allCircuits[n]], {n, 1, 10}]
(* {1, 2, 4, 9, 22, 53, 131, 337, 869, 2213} *)
```

which you can read more about in [OEIS A048211](https://oeis.org/A048211).

Comment: +1, nice work. That solved my problem. Just one more question if that can be done. Because all resistors are same, so there are some duplcates such as `s[s[R,R],R],s[R,s[R,R]]` ,etc, would it be possible to delete  duplicates?

Comment: @emnha, please see my update. Also, I strongly suggest reading [OEIS A048211](https://oeis.org/A048211) and the links therein, which might help answering your question.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 4;
rs = Table[R, n];
ts = Tuples[{p, s}, {n - 1}];
combs = Riffle[rs, #] & /@ ts;
eqvres = First@FixedPoint[
      SequenceReplace[#
        , {{h___, x_, p, y_, k___} :> Sequence[h, (x y)/(x + y), k]
         , {h___, x_, s, y_, k___} :> Sequence[h, x + y, k]
         }] &, #] & /@ combs;
```

*Visualization*

```
Transpose[{combs, eqvres}] /. { p -> "∥", 
    s -> "≈"} // Map[MapAt[Row, #, {1}] &] // 
 Grid[#, Alignment -> Center, ItemSize -> {Automatic, 2}, 
   Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is above my level but it works, nice  visualization and much faster than Domen's version.

Comment: For large n such as 17 it is still slow. I don't know how long it would take.

Comment: What is your application? You may want to contact [Analog Insydes](https://www.itwm.fraunhofer.de/en/departments/sys/products-and-services/analog-insydes.html) if symbolic circuit modeling and analysis is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to find the minimum number of resistors (together with the circuit connections) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160766/how-many-resistors-are-needed

Comment: Put your intended application and this link in the post and it will get more visibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, this version is missing cases.
For example with three resistors R1, R2, R3
the case where (R1 in series with R2 first) and then in parallel with R3 is not included.

Comment: What should that evaluate to given identical resistors?

Comment: `(R≈R)∥R = 2R/3`

Comment: See if reversing the order of rules in `SequenceReplace` will fix it for you.

Comment: That would add `2R/3` but it misses `3R/2`.

Comment: This is a comment to the OP:  OEIS A048211 (and your `allCircuits` function) states that there are 9 possibilities for $n=4$.  But @Syed shows the 8 (=2^(n-1)) arrangements.  What might be the 9th arrangement?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see now.  It is not just looking at the 2^(n-1) combinations from left to right (or right to left).  It involves other groupings (hence, `Groupings` now makes sense).  The "groupings" that are missing are labeled `{p[p[s[R, R], R], R], p[s[p[R, R], R], R], p[s[s[R, R], R], R], s[p[s[R, R], R], R]}`.  (And I also now see that `allCircuits` was written by @Domen.)