# Is there a way to optimize it for larger n?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction

This is Domen's code from my previous thread [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290774/how-to-calculate-equivalent-resistance-for-a-network-of-same-value-resistors/290779?noredirect=1#comment723074_290779). I think it covers all the cases that I mentioned there and works well for small values of `n`. However, for large values of `n`, such as `n=10` or `n=20`, it takes a very long time. I don't know how long it would take, as I haven't been able to run it to completion yet. Is there any way to speed it up for large `n`?

```
ClearAll[p, s];
p[R1_, R2_] := 1/(1/R1 + 1/R2);
s[R1_, R2_] := R1 + R2;
n = 3
Groupings[Table[R, n], {p -> 2, s -> 2}]
```

Comment: I haven't had time to answer to your comment in that answer, so I'll ask here: Do you really want to generate _all_ possible circuits? If the three resistors are different, the number of possible circuits grows [very fast](https://oeis.org/A151374) (ie. $2489344$ for $n=10$ and $926554883358720$ for $n=20$). If I understood correctly your previous comment, you only want to get circuits for three equal resistors that have unique equivalent resistance?

Comment: @Domen I want to get all different circuits (unique ones without duplicates) for a given equivalent resistance values. For the second question, yes, all resistors are same.

Comment: Doesn't `IntegerPartitions[n]` give you a listing of the possible combinations to examine?

Comment: From your previous thread I now see that `IntegerPartitions[n-1]` would only be useful if one was applying functions `p` and `s` from left to right (or right to left).  But there are other groupings such that `RpRsRpR` can be evaluated in different orders (`((RpR) sR) pR` and `(RpR) s (RpR)`) to obtain `3R/5` and `R`, respectively.  However, if the resistance value of interest is one generated by just the left-to-right assessment, then there would be considerable time savings.

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title.  After all, what is "it"?

Comment: @JimB your observation is correct. It is two-directional assessment.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I meant the code given in the post.

Comment: @emnha:  Right, but your title is *STILL* extremely poor.  The reader should get an understanding ***from the title*** what the problem is about.  "It" simply won't do it.  Please fix the poor title.